# equality of two double array

Tags: java, arrays

i have problem with testing two double arrays if they are equals i wrote this method

```
    public static boolean equalsArray(double[]a,double[]b){
    if(a.length!=b.length)
        return false;
    else{
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        if(a[i]!=b[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and every time when i use it i get false!!
for example:

```
double []a={1.7,6.9};
double []b={1.7,6.9};
System.out.println(equalsArray(a,b));
```

it works fine with int arrays but with double it doesn't

Thanks so much

Comment: Returns `true` in my case. BTW, you can use `Arrays.equals()`

Comment: Is that your actual test case? or just an example? It should return `true`.

Comment: I don't see a question here. The code snippet you posted works just fine(it returns true in the case mentioned).

Comment: my mistake was i forget to delete some method that change the arrays

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/205351/addition-of-doubles-is-not-equal-to-sum-of-the-double-as-a-whole

Answer (score 1):

Best way to compare double values is:

```
double a = 1.000000;
    double b = 1.000009;
    if(Math.abs(a-b)<=0.00000001){
        System.out.println("equal");
    }
```

`0.00000001` is called `epsilon` and you can adjust it accordingly.

Comment: 1) The question is about comparing two *arrays* of doubles, not just two doubles. 2) I wouldn't call something that prints out the result rather than returning it the "best way"

Comment: @DennisMeng in array also we are comparing two doubles. it's not advisable to compare two doubles like this.